# Node.js Streaming after change in file

Tags: node.js

how make stream to browser without refresh? For example: i write somthing in file and in browser display my text.

Comment: Do you want to watch a file for changes and let that show up in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sockets. Try the `socket.io` package: `npm install socket.io`.

If you want to read/write a stream, you can pipe the stream to socket.io.

Comment: Only socket.io? I need make log analyzer and I want stream to admin panel logs.

Comment: Socket.io will allow you to communicate real time between the client and server.  You're going to need to create something on the server side to load the logs in real time, that's where piping the stream to socket.io comes into play.

Comment: Ok, have you any example, tutorial...?